# Create a variable from 2 Tkinter entries

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to get the first three characters of a Tkinter entry, and then add them to another tkinter entry.

For example:

```
name = Entry=(root, text="Name: ")

age = Entry=(root, text="Age: ")
```

`username` = First three characters of name + age

Then I want the first three letters of their name to add to the age to create a user name.
If the user enters 'Taylor' as a 'name' and '13' as a 'age', I want to make a variable called 'username' which would contain 'Tay13'

Not sure if I made it too clear, but hopefully you understand. Thanks

EDIT: Just tried something else and it says 'StringVar' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: It would be pretty insane to define a variable that dynamically, at least let the user enter that information using a button...

Comment: _"Just tried something else..."_ Why don't you go ahead and post that so you're not wasting other people's time who may be trying what you already tried? Post your code attempts - right now this question is low quality.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out how to do it on Reddit. If any one else need this, then here is the answer:

*username = name.get()[:3] + age.get()*

**This gets the first 3 letters from 'name' and adds 'age' on to the end of it.**

Thanks to the people who helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get the username. The `[:3]` pulls the first 3 letters of a string.

```
username = str(name[:3]) + str(age)
print username
```

Comment: It says 'StringVar' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

Below example adds/updates id to `users` dictionary each time the button is pressed:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def update_users():
    global users, name, age
    user_id = name.get()[:3] + age.get()
    users[user_id] = None
    print(users)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    users = dict()
    name = tk.Entry(root)
    age = tk.Entry(root)
    update_btn  = tk.Button(root, text="Update Users", command=update_users)
    name.pack()
    age.pack()
    update_btn.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This how to go about this create two `entry` widget to receive the content in the entry.Then your `funtion` to print the content in the `entry` and `slice` the first three letters of the name and print plus the age.

```
from tkinter import *


def Print_variable():
    e1 = name.get()
    e2 = age.get()
    print(e1[:3] + e2)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

name = StringVar()  
e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=name)   # this entry accept the name
e1.pack()

age = StringVar()
e2 = Entry(root, textvariable=age)  # this entry accept the age
e2.pack()

b = Button(root, text="print name and age variable", command=Print_variable)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```